# populate mysql table on the basis of another

Tags: php, mysql, database, compare

I have 3 mysql tables containing a few fields. Please refer to the following

```
--------  --------  --------
table 1 | table 2 | table 3
--------  --------  --------
a_id    | b_id    | email
                  | a_id
name    | status  | b_id
email_1 | date    | name
phone   | ref     | phone
address | email_2 | address
state   | from    | state
                  | status
                  | date
                  | ref
                  | from
```

The **email_1** and **email_2** is exactly same.

I need to populate the table3 fields with all table1 and table2 data. But I need to store them in one row based on email. So they look like following:

```
=================================================================================
                                   table 3
=================================================================================
email | a_id | b_id | name | phone | address | state | status | date | ref | from
------+------+------+------+-------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----+-----
a@x.co|  9   | 112  | John |  999  | xxxx    |   NY  |    0   | 15Jue| dave|  y
------+------+------+------+-------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----+-----
b@x.co|  6   | 338  | Sue  |  909  | xxxx    |   NY  |    1   | 12Jue| kell|  z
------+------+------+------+-------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----+-----
c@x.co|  3   | 152  | John |  679  | xxxx    |   NY  |    1   | 10Jue| lois|  g
------+------+------+------+-------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----+-----
d@x.co|  8   | 145  | John |  599  | xxxx    |   NY  |    0   | 8Jue | sue |  f
```

I can't figure it out how to do that. I'm using core php, mysql. Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `SELECT ... INTO ...`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.email_1 = table_2.email_2`

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Since there is a lot of data, I can't understand what should be the query. I'm quite new in php, mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this for mysql:

```
insert into table_3
(
    `email`,
    `a_id`,
    `b_id`,
    `name`,
    `phone`,
    `address`,
    `state`,
    `status`,
    `date`,
    `ref`,
    `from`
)
select
    `a`.`email_1`,
    `a`.`a_id`,
    `b`.`b_id`,
    `a`.`name`,
    `a`.`phone`,
    `a`.`address`,
    `a`.`state`,
    `b`.`status`,
    `b`.`date`,
    `b`.`ref`,
    `b`.`from`
from 
    table_1 as `a`
    inner join
    table_2 as `b` on `a`.`email_1` = `b`.`email_2`
```

But you should probably go read up on [MySQL insert syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to see it's power, and on [joining data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) :)

Comment: True, the keywords should be properly escaped in the query, but then again, the schema shouldn't contain keywords in the first place! :) Query updated...

Comment: @nover: Thank you so much :) Perfectly works! Just to let you know, the quotation ('') stuffs does not seem to be worked. Once they are removed it worked like charm. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @MohammadKhalidMasud That's probably because you are using it through PHP and then it's very likely that the MySQLI driver does the escaping for you-however to run it properly in a query editor the manual escaping is necessary. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_3(`email`,`a_id`,`b_id`,`name`,`phone`,`address`,`state`,`status`,`date`,`ref`,`from`)
select `email_1`,`a_id`,`b_id`,`name`,`phone`,`address`,`state`,`status`,`date`,`ref`,`from`
from table_1,table_2
where email_1=email_2;
```

Comment: AFAIK mysql does not support select ... into table syntax. It only supports selecting into a variable. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: @hammurabi Also, be careful with the "," JOIN operator-when used without the ON clause (as in this query) you are creating a Cartesian Product-all possible combination of the data in the two tables. On large databases this hurts performance badly. See the docs regarding INNER join and COMMA join: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html